# Hum happens with one guitar but not another

Tags: electric-guitar, pick-ups, noise

I'm having a problem that many of you must have already had. I have an old guitar with old humbuckers ( a Jolana, Galaxis model, 1970's Czech guitar) that is producing that classing "not grounded" noise that disappears when you touch any metal part from the guitar. I know that the amplifier should be properly grounded etc, and it is not; it's connected to a 220-110v stepdown transformer. But the thing is,  I also have an Epiphone Les Paul custom that even when plugged in this same not grounded configuration doesn't produce any hum or noise at all. Do you guys have any Idea why does this happen? If it was only because of grounding, the noise should happen In any guitar right?

Comment: This obviously suggests some issue with the Jolana. Perhaps some ground connections are bad due to cold or broken solder joints? Perhaps pickups are of worse quality, or damaged? Perhaps the electronic cavity needs shielding?... The issue might be easy to solve or might be very difficult. A guitar tech may help.

Comment: I had the same problem last week with a bass. A dry joint was the problem, solved when re-soldered.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm certainly checking those solder joints!